# Get x recent posts by author?

Tags: posts, author, get-posts, recent-posts

So I have ten authors on my site, and I want to designate a section where it shows the ten authors and their 5 latest posts in the form of the post title linking to the post.

I tried using the following

```
<?php get_most_recent_post_of_user( $user_id ); ?>
```

But it doesn't work, so I'm feeling a bit lost.

Any advice/suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

The function you are using, [`get_most_recent_post_of_user`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_most_recent_post_of_user), won't work as it only retrieves the latest **post** from the author. It cannot retieve a list of posts

> Walks through each of a user's blogs to find the post with the most recent post_date_gmt.

You will most probably be better of using either [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Author_Parameters) or `get_posts` to achieve this.

You should first add all your author ID's in an array or use a custom function to dynamically get them, and then use a `foreach` loop and loop through all the separate ID`s and using each ID in a custom query to retrieve the latest 5 posts from that author